# How to Convert java to kotlin in handler

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

how to Convert java to kotlin in handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
        Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        Splash.this.finish();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: You can use `Code-> Convert Java File to Kotlin File` as a start. You can also just paste this code in a Kotlin file and it will be converted for you.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Java converted to Kotlin:

```kotlin
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    val mainIntent = Intent(this, Menu::class.java)
    startActivity(mainIntent)
    finish()
}, 3000)
```

---

If you are using the androidx-core-ktx package, there is an [extension function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/os/package-summary#(android.os.Handler).postDelayed(kotlin.Long,kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function0)) which reorders the arguments to be more suitable for Kotlin:

```kotlin
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(1000) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: @creativecoder The default constructor is deprecated. It now specifies the main looper to avoid this issue and to make sure the delayed code is always run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Declare Duration of splash screen display (in milliseconds)
    private val SPLASH_DURATION = 2000L 

Inside - onCreate()

Handler().postDelayed({
           val intent = Intent(this, ActivityLogin::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
           finish()
        }, SPLASH_DURATION)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    
    // Establecer el modo noche predeterminado en "Modo noche apagado" (MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }, 3000); //5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
}
```

Comment: en java 2023 funciona perfectamente asi

Comment: Use english for both kinds of comments please.